# Inequality involving modulus of functions

Tags: inequality

May I know how to I prove the result

$|f(x)|<g(x) \iff [-g(x)<f(x)<g(x)]$?

In particular, could I know why the following works?

$(|x|<2x)⟹(−2x<x<2x)⟹(−2x<x$ and $x<2x)⟹(x>0$ and $x>0)⟹(x>0)$.

The result seems to work even when $2x$ is not guaranteed to be non-negative.

Comment: What are your thoughts and what did you try?

Comment: I have no inkling how to start.

Comment: Can you prove $|a| < b \Longleftrightarrow -b < a < b$?

Comment: Yes for non negative b. However, I struggle when I tried to replace b with g(x) which can possibly be negative.

Comment: @KHOOS no it can't. Absolute values are *always* positive so something larger than them must be positive too.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think my question could be clearer. Could I know why the following works?

$(|x|<2x) \implies (-2x<x<2x) \implies (-2x<x$ and $x<2x) \implies  (x>0$ and $x>0) \implies  (x>0)$.

The result seems to work even when $2x$ is not guaranteed to be non-negative.

Comment: Can I say that for $c>0$,
$|a|<c$
$\iff (a\geq0~\text{and}~|a|<c)~\text{or}~(a<0~\text{and}~|a|<c)$
$\iff (a\geq0~\text{and}~a<c)~\text{or}~(a<0~\text{and}~a>-c)$
$\iff 0\leq a<c~\text{or}~-c<a<0$
$\iff -c<a<c$.

Comment: And for $c\leq0$,
$|a|<c$
$\iff (a\geq0~\text{and}~|a|<c)~\text{or}~(a<0~\text{and}~|a|<c)$
$\iff (a\geq0~\text{and}~a<c)~\text{or}~(a<0~\text{and}~a>-c)$
$\iff 0\leq a<c~\text{or}~-c<a<0$
$\iff \varnothing~\text{or}~\varnothing$
$\iff -c<a<c$.

Comment: Since $a$ and $c$ are arbitrary real numbers, hence $|f(x)|<g(x) \iff -g(x)<f(x)<g(x)$ holds for all $x$ in both the domains of f and g?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The key is in the definition:

$$|\alpha|=\begin{cases} \alpha & \alpha\geq 0  \\  -\alpha & \alpha<0 & \end{cases}$$